# curl command not found on .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: curl, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a .gitlab-ci.yml file. Its creating some docker images and pushing it to AWS ECR.

When I am running curl command to push some artifacts to remote repository it says curl: not found. I am already using openjdk image to do ./gradlew build. Don't know how to install curl on Gitlab runner.

Please guide.

Comment: Please add a minimal .gitlab-ci.yml file for this problem

Answer (score 25):

I was able to resolve it by using apk utility.

```
apk add --update curl && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

Or more recently using [`no-cache`](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/blob/master/docs/usage.md#disabling-cache):

```
apk add --no-cache curl
```

Comment: this one was really useful. Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting `apk: command not found`

Answer (score 17):

If you're using `docker:dind`, you can do the following as @Abhinav Mutreja mentioned.

```
image: docker:stable

services:
  - name: docker:dind

stages:
  - example

example:
  stage: example
  before_script:
    - apk add --update curl && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
  script:
    - >
      curl google.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Installing `curl` in the runner container works. Here is an example:

```
trigger_xpub_epmc:
  stage: deploy
  image: docker:stable
  before_script:
    - apk add --update curl && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
  script:
    - curl -X POST -F token=xxxxx -F ref=master https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1934/trigger/pipeline
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to install curl  in `before_script` by `- apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl git jq`

```
before_script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl git jq
 script:
    - curl -F document=@"/app-release.apk"
```

and to upload to telegram channel

```
- curl -F document=@"app/build/outputs/apk/release/${APPLICATION_NAME}${APPLICATION_VERSION}.apk" -F caption="${TELEGRAM_MESSAGE_CAPTION}" https://api.telegram.org/bot${TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN}/sendDocument?chat_id=${TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID}
```

Comment: Why do you install `git` and `jk`?