# Use CURL within GitLab

Tags: github, curl, gitlab, github-api

I am using GitLab and would like to call within the .yml file an URL. I do have following .yml file so far:

```
stages:
  - test

L15-Release:    
  stage: test
  script:
    - curl -X POST "http://www.test.com" 
  when: manual
  tags:
    - ts
```

How can I call such http site with the curl command?

Thanks.

Comment: It may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46031069/curl-command-not-found-on-gitlab-ci-yml

Comment: is it possible to save the curl.exe directly on the gitlab server in order to call it afterwards?

Comment: you have to install the curl and in the precedent link it shows how to do it with before_script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [curl command not found on .gitlab-ci.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46031069/curl-command-not-found-on-gitlab-ci-yml)

Comment: The answer depends on which [executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/) you are using.

Comment: I am using a powershell executor. So is it possible to install the curl.exe on the gitlab server in order to call a job (as done in the .yml file above) at any PC with the gitlab-runner?

Comment: You'd need to install curl on the runner host in this case. This might or might not be the same as your GitLab host.

Comment: ok - how does the curl request within the .yml file looks like if it is installed on the host? Do you have an example?